# How to stop JavaScript from sending multiple AJAX requests before finishing the first one sent

Tags: javascript, flask

I am taking the CS50 Web Programming course and in one of the examples, the instructor shows us how to implement a functionality in which new posts are loaded when we scroll to the bottom of the page, using Flask and Vanilla JS.

The problem is that when I scroll to the bottom of the page, instead of loading only 20 posts, which is what is defined in the code, JavaScript sends multiple AJAX requests at once, thus loading 40, 60 or even 80 posts at once.

I used console.log to check if the variables were being updated correctly, and they are. So, what I understood is that when I scroll to the bottom of the page, JavaScript is sending several requests to load new posts, before the first ones requested finish being displayed.

How can I make the webpage make only 1 request after I scroll to the bottom of the page and wait until all the posts have been appended to the body until I can scroll again to the bottom of the page and therefore make a new request?

Code is below.

Flask:

```
import time

from flask import Flask, jsonify, render_template, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route("/posts", methods=["POST"])
def posts():

    # Get start and end point for posts to generate.
    start = int(request.form.get("start") or 0)
    end = int(request.form.get("end") or (start + 9))

    # Generate list of posts.
    data = []
    for i in range(start, end + 1):
        data.append(f"Post #{i}")

    # Artificially delay speed of response.
    time.sleep(1)

    # Return list of posts.
    return jsonify(data)
```

JS+HTML+CSS

```
        <style>
            .post {
                background-color: #77dd11;
                padding: 20px;
                margin: 10px;
            }

            body {
                padding-bottom: 50px;
            }
        </style>
        <script>

            // Start with first post.
            let counter = 1;

            // Load posts 20 at a time.
            const quantity = 20;

            // When DOM loads, render the first 20 posts.
            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', load);

            // If scrolled to bottom, load the next 20 posts.
            window.onscroll = () => {
                if (window.innerHeight + window.scrollY >= document.body.offsetHeight) {
                    load();
                }
            };

            // Load next set of posts.
            function load() {

                // Set start and end post numbers, and update counter.
                const start = counter;
                const end = start + quantity - 1;
                counter = end + 1;

                // Open new request to get new posts.
                const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
                request.open('POST', '/posts');
                request.onload = () => {
                    const data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
                    data.forEach(add_post);
                };

                // Add start and end points to request data.
                const data = new FormData();
                data.append('start', start);
                data.append('end', end);

                // Send request.
                request.send(data);
            };

            // Add a new post with given contents to DOM.
            function add_post(contents) {

                // Create new post.
                const post = document.createElement('div');
                post.className = 'post';
                post.innerHTML = contents;

                // Add post to DOM.
                document.querySelector('#posts').append(post);
            };
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="posts">
        </div>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, it is better to switch to the more powerful `fetch` API, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API, and in your code's case it is probably a better idea to use the async/await pattern. so you turn your `load()` function into `async load()` and also the onscroll function like `window.onscroll = async () => {...}`. Here is a code sample of how you could refactor your code below.

```
// If scrolled to bottom, load the next 20 posts.
        window.onscroll = async () => {
            if (window.innerHeight + window.scrollY >= document.body.offsetHeight) {
                await load();
            }
        };

        // Load next set of posts.
        async function load() {

            // Set start and end post numbers, and update counter.
            const start = counter;
            const end = start + quantity - 1;
            counter = end + 1;


            // Add start and end points to request data.
            const data = new FormData();
            data.append('start', start);
            data.append('end', end);

            // Send request with the fetch API and using await on it
            let resultText = await fetch('/posts', {method: 'POST'});
            const data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
            data.forEach(add_post);
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (window.innerHeight + window.scrollY >= document.body.offsetHeight) {
   load();
}
```

the onscroll event fires really fast multiple times every time you scroll. When you scroll to the bottom of the page, your if condition is true multiple times, firing multiple requests. You need to make sure it will only fire once.

```
let fetching = false
if (window.innerHeight + window.scrollY >= document.body.offsetHeight && !fetching) {
   fetching = true
   load();
}
```

That way it won't start another request when there's one in progress. Then just set the fetching flag to false again when your request comes back.

```
request.onload = () => {
   const data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
   data.forEach(add_post);
   fetching = false
};
```